# SQL Server - convert short date in from old database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, type-conversion

I have old DBF database that contains date in old 6 digit formats like `291292` or `150793` or even `010302`.

I import tables into SQL Server and now I need to convert it to `datetime` format.

Of course must be converted to similar strings `29.12.1992`, `15.07.1993`, `01.03.2002` first.

Comment: What is the logic for converting one of these dates, that is, to which date does e.g. `291292` correspond?

Comment: `291292` is `1992-12-29` in US format

Comment: Surely the US format? Us is MDY: 12-29-1992

Comment: well may be i wrong but mssql store dates in yyyy-mm-dd format :)

Comment: What have you tried? Because this seems rather simple... e.g. casting the 5th and 6th characters plus the 3rd and 4th characters plus the 1st and 2nd characters as a date is pretty straightforward...

Comment: Note : SQL Server does not store dates in any particular or specific format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it pretty simple:

```
GO
    declare @date varchar(6)
    set @date = '241190'
    select CONVERT(date, concat(SUBSTRING(@date, 5,2),SUBSTRING(@date, 3,2),SUBSTRING(@date, 1,2)), 101) as [Date]
```

result is `1990-11-24`

Answer (score 1):

You may try this.

```
    GO
    declare @date date
    set @date = '901124'
    select CONVERT(varchar(10), @date, 102) as [Date]   --- for yyyy.MM.dd format
```

**TRY THIS**

```
    declare @dd varchar(10)
    set @dd = '201292'

    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @dd, 2),   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 2) 
    , (SUBSTRING(@dd, 5,2) +  SUBSTRING(@dd, 3,2)  + SUBSTRING(@dd, 1,2))
    ,   CONVERT(varchar(10), cast((SUBSTRING(@dd, 5,2) +  SUBSTRING(@dd, 3,2)  + SUBSTRING(@dd, 1,2)) as DATE) , 102)
```

Comment: I have `ddmmyy` date formats and try code in `update1` see question, but sadly it did not convert to date just give me a string `901124`

Answer (score -1):

```
     declare @date date = '901124'   
   select CONVERT(date, @date) as [Date]
```

[image]

Comment: Please also add some explanation to your answer.